# How can I debug a PUT request in Rails 3.1?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ios, restkit

I am developing a simple iOS app, which uses a Rails app as a server backend. I'm using the Restkit framework for the management of the server networking / requests and on the iOS side all seems to be OK.

When I make a PUT request, I get a 200 response back, and the logs in XCode seem to suggest all is well. When I look at the logs for the Rails app, it also seems to suggest all is well, with the following output:

```
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Started PUT "/lists/3/tasks/6" for 109.156.183.65 at 2011-12-19 18:15:17 +0000
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"created_at"=>"2011-12-12 22:37:00 +0000", "id"=>"6", "updated_at"=>"2011-12-12 22:37:00 +0000", "description"=>"Create a home page", "list_id"=>"3", "completed"=>"1"}
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Task Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "6"]]
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by TasksController#update as JSON
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]:    (4.7ms)  BEGIN
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.5ms)  COMMIT
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 1.1ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 109.156.183.65 - - [19/Dec/2011:10:15:17 -0800] "PUT /lists/3/tasks/6 HTTP/1.1" 200 154 "-" "TaskM8/1.0 CFNetwork/485.13.9 Darwin/11.2.0" taskm8.com
2011-12-19T18:15:17+00:00 heroku[router]: PUT taskm8.com/lists/3/tasks/6 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=114ms status=200 bytes=154
```

However, when I make another get request, or use the standard web views to look at the data, the change I was expecting from the PUT request (Completed = 1 - which is a BOOL field), no change has been made.

I can see from the rails log that my iOS app is passing the correct parameters, so it seems to be something on the rails side. I've been through the loop of overcoming the CSRF error message, so don't think it's that.

On a local version of the rails app, I've also run general logging against the MySql database to monitor the queries being run, trying to see if the PUT does anything at all, or anything which would fail... in the log, you don't see anything other than:

```
 BEGIN
 COMMIT
```

The same as the rails log.

So, does anyone have any idea about why the PUT is not making the changes to the data, or how I can debug the PUT further?

Apologies if this is a real simple question, I'm slowly getting back into development and am somewhat rusty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any kind of automated tests? If not, start there.

Another way (though rubbish) would be to call your controller action from a webpage and see if it works.

You can also add `logger.debug` in your rails code to add traces.

Comment: Thanks Dominic. logger.debug doesn't seem to add anything, the log output is the same as before, I assume because the log level is already debug for the development environment?  In regards to through the browser, if I use the classic rails edit view, then submit which calls the PUT, it works fine... I'm not using any automated tests, will have a look into that, any pointers on good docs to start with?

Comment: Hmmm, actually... when using the edit view in the browser, the put does get called in the same way, but for some reason the Update SQL gets called... I think my problem is to do with nested models, because I see extra parameters in the browser version.     Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update Task", "authenticity_token"=>"5AmRnSsqrOlVrgHlENOdage8TZkwR6QPInOUHATUjv8=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "id"=>"4", "list_id"=>"6", "task"=>{"completed"=>"1", "list_id"=>"6", "description"=>"Be a good boy for a whole day"}}

Comment: `logger.debug` is not a flag, it's a method where you should pass what you want to be logged, such as `logger.debug "======= my debug trace ======="`

Comment: And for automated tests, I would strongly suggest to go to railscasts.com and search for rspec there.

Comment: Thanks Dominic - Your simple prompt that I should look more closely at the log of the webpage actions made me realise that this was a problem caused predominantly by my limited understanding of routing. I was trying to update a model through a route which expected it to be wrapped within its parent - it was expecting a list.task, rather than a task directly.  Thanks very much for drawing me to the obvious...  I'll also look into rspec.  M

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the MySQL server I would suggest that you enable the [general lo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html)g aka the query log, that way you can see what really happens.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/tmp/query.log'
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: Thanks Andreas - As mentioned, I've done that already... you see only BEGIN .. COMMIT in the general log.